# Setting of Spring's XML

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, classpath

I have classpath settings for Spring's xml file "scanimagereport-data.xml" in the "resources" folder as following photos.

It works fine when I run it as Java Application in Eclipse.

However, the xml file can't be found and read when I export the program to jar file and run it in DOS command prompt.

Have found how to set the classpath for some time.  But still don't know how to make it works.  Hope someone can help...

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: hk.net.tsl.scanimagereport.run.FtpFilesSvcTesting

Name: org/apache/xml/serializer/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xml.serializer
Implementation-Version: 2.7.0
Specification-Vendor: W3C Recommendation 16 November 1999
Specification-Title: XSL Transformations (XSLT), at http://www.w3.org/
 TR/xslt
Implementation-URL: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html
Specification-Version: 1.0
Comment: Serializer to write out XML, HTML etc. as a stream of charact
 ers from an input DOM or from input SAX events.

Name: javax/mail/internet/ContentDisposition.class
SHA1-Digest: bY8UAj9xFRzI4/VCQoGyGPwOknY=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/Protocol.class
SHA1-Digest: wAZ7DkPdNZ+OYMCu0UtkSziBRB4=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/Response.class
SHA1-Digest: tFgqRdpA3+0smuOFCBibO03uhGo=

Name: com/sun/mail/smtp/DigestMD5.class
SHA1-Digest: 8CdePxmLZUwQUSN6YGvMX9U/ml0=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimePart.class
SHA1-Digest: V5t0/G+DkCx8EdNkvIdq+1R6IH0=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.class
SHA1-Digest: S7pebUjNqfxvaK2ELFhBqa0Nr8s=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Rights.class
SHA1-Digest: ilk6VAwKfEvDqMSeBypwRK7kSqU=

Name: javax/mail/Message.class
SHA1-Digest: krXNUG849vk3hdRK5/IJ7/RPAQQ=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/SocketFetcher.class
SHA1-Digest: T77YEuZtS8y6usz9EfITXwz3l5o=

Name: javax/mail/ReadOnlyFolderException.class
SHA1-Digest: S0Nq1oqW9uyNAyk/Kqqr/1kYQA0=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Store.class
SHA1-Digest: tfboxyMbD/NbEBFQTb2cz+3cuJ8=

Name: javax/mail/event/TransportListener.class
SHA1-Digest: ZsaUmiJzCAKO4AcGnHFxgUVLA1Q=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12$2.class
SHA1-Digest: E2rXTlPkQT/6PiuZBBW3ffk61qE=

Name: javax/mail/search/HeaderTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: lZ/h2u1F6TnaF0Ih840anZ3HtC8=

Name: org/apache/xml/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xml
Implementation-URL: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dist/
Implementation-Version: 2.7.0
Comment: DTM implementation and utilities

Name: javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.class
SHA1-Digest: Y9+glLmoLdTkOLCbedr8fyTC+eY=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/SearchSequence.class
SHA1-Digest: t2xolWv3jNpoa9CE+SfEORDRuXk=

Name: javax/mail/Session.class
SHA1-Digest: dG/hsdEjivnjb5tL4PAX2sIYOQE=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Item.class
SHA1-Digest: jt+5t84a7Lj6fTDiFf92jLnL904=

Name: javax/mail/search/IntegerComparisonTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: hsilLJNY6jikGSPm1rGXFdopW8Q=

Name: javax/mail/search/DateTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: sJMnSc8K9JfZvo9PWwDOYAKOGU8=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility$1$NullInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: M9e0IjrHqAAdEVS3miejIauY4KA=

Name: javax/mail/Address.class
SHA1-Digest: X7VSByL8WAotQCpAT/5Q5AKA89c=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/QPEncoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: FuVz6KvMT/IkJop8gKdaPktAC+I=

Name: javax/mail/MessageRemovedException.class
SHA1-Digest: flx99/N4bVa1FiDB42u8k5xn8sI=

Name: javax/mail/event/MessageChangedEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: Iglkwqm3yZsZ6oA1fCkyEiPF0N0=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMultipartDataSource.class
SHA1-Digest: O4vXDVAskJ8+XwSGq+zSIWNMO1Q=

Name: javax/mail/internet/NewsAddress.class
SHA1-Digest: CpknF4BJMRS67HdzJm6Jxq/ZsYc=

Name: javax/mail/MultipartDataSource.class
SHA1-Digest: q5t9m5Z6jIVYd+Ndb52UMWIX9Sw=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ConnectionException.class
SHA1-Digest: sDlarplfMMKV4E9T0ytDBg1+AJc=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/FetchResponse.class
SHA1-Digest: 3rfxnONvQhT88oHQfH2h9gX5Z5E=

Name: javax/mail/search/OrTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: LEcwqC/g3wjd7vvkRv87Brz8LHE=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/BadCommandException.class
SHA1-Digest: j+cPDx9IHpfzOGLdgxIVf7Hne00=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder$2.class
SHA1-Digest: 8Vp1Jwzz1Xz0gg5F0hQ5uLiT+O0=

Name: javax/mail/event/MessageChangedListener.class
SHA1-Digest: CO4WmyMgpnfmTeMqRB10BP3E/IQ=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPResponse.class
SHA1-Digest: 9IZiUHugnKLCAsUg98xb/zjcVBU=

Name: javax/mail/search/MessageNumberTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: gSem31OGV4jMswkFOm1jvgJZ8aY=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/SharedFileInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: dDw5OXYtjVCV4Q8Maq8O/J5Jp1Q=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/LiteralException.class
SHA1-Digest: Jag5t9w1nm01xHUIN48a5ZG41hU=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/Literal.class
SHA1-Digest: jMeEDxmF2B1WQSZegHaS20Z3nDU=

Name: javax/mail/MessageAware.class
SHA1-Digest: jp3hq8pfG9lfLtSB0cL2M85ccSQ=

Name: org/apache/xpath/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xpath
Implementation-URL: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dist/
Implementation-Version: 2.7.0
Comment: XPath engine

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/ACL.class
SHA1-Digest: lLEvhMBKrtNrsJguz0kzaRmS/oU=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/ListInfo.class
SHA1-Digest: OVcXT5i+QD+NA8zn2JMxd1FbKhk=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.class
SHA1-Digest: 4rkNeeC9kyNgI3WY1yn7cTVsHPA=

Name: javax/mail/search/SearchException.class
SHA1-Digest: rquY7mBKZYtM4ee2teSKciP2FDI=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$6.class
SHA1-Digest: dvZwqaJ3yuk1N1q6tQ26H2MQOns=

Name: org/apache/xalan/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xalan
Implementation-Version: 2.7.0
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: Java API for XML Processing
Implementation-URL: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dist/
Specification-Version: 1.3
Comment: Main Xalan engine implementing TrAX/JAXP

Name: javax/mail/Transport.class
SHA1-Digest: 5sAOVdCTkoP/4FEaCxalhGC8T/s=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: w8HgIwmzknu+2uR7DQjevxjhLvc=

Name: JBossRemoting
Implementation-Vendor: JBoss Inc.
Implementation-Title: JBossRemoting
Implementation-Version: 2.2.2.SP8
Implementation-Vendor-Id: http://www.jboss.org
Specification-Vendor: JBoss Inc.
Specification-Title: JBossRemoting
Specification-Version: 2.2.2.SP8

Name: javax/mail/Header.class
SHA1-Digest: 4kh6YmNXUKdkArYO5u312kmV3eQ=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MailDateParser.class
SHA1-Digest: yNuQXmcNZcKpBtxXKb2Dgr/jhKY=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BODYSTRUCTURE.class
SHA1-Digest: 0+l+fhktBXRP0MOfnYM9Z/MHkP0=

Name: javax/mail/internet/ParameterList.class
SHA1-Digest: 9jIFa9qxIjZM0ff35d85/YgdRQM=

Name: javax/mail/URLName.class
SHA1-Digest: vs7Akz89DBR8IJvhvziUuBai8lc=

Name: javax/xml/transform/
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.xml.transform
Implementation-Version: 1.3.02
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: Java API for XML Processing
Implementation-URL: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp.html
Specification-Version: 1.3
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: javax/mail/event/ConnectionEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: cjGrDkhnqGTdPV0/0/s8u2HOmoY=

Name: org/xml/sax/
Implementation-Vendor: David Megginson
Implementation-Title: org.xml.sax
Implementation-Version: 2.0.2
Specification-Vendor: David Megginson
Specification-Title: Simple API for XML
Implementation-URL: http://www.saxproject.org/
Specification-Version: 2.0.2
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.01

Name: org/w3c/dom/
Implementation-Vendor: World Wide Web Consortium
Implementation-Title: org.w3c.dom
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Vendor: World Wide Web Consortium
Specification-Title: Document Object Model, Level 3 Core
Implementation-URL: http://www.w3c.org/DOM/
Specification-Version: 1.0
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: javax/mail/search/FlagTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: ywIxPYyzdgTa1BL7sXuKb3hcyGo=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ResponseHandler.class
SHA1-Digest: PscpGXa4y5TeSxv6FO/YCRiALUA=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Utility.class
SHA1-Digest: pNQrlz/sCl8/CIAqurzRkI4UaXA=

Name: javax/mail/FolderClosedException.class
SHA1-Digest: qEdMfsKFRg3FBlByevo1dfnzS24=

Name: javax/mail/event/FolderEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: 5HsowfXxLX3Ss7m8/9ST2fbmBIc=

Name: javax/mail/internet/hdr.class
SHA1-Digest: Jpc1bcsAto5zLWEO7SJcKRAMTbg=

Name: javax/mail/FetchProfile.class
SHA1-Digest: xNwmiCwbbGCR4kuX6B6G+8M7BDQ=
Name: org/apache/xerces/xni/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xerces.xni
Implementation-Version: 1.2
Specification-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Specification-Title: Xerces Native Interface
Implementation-URL: http://xml.apache.org/xerces2-j/
Specification-Version: 1.2
Comment: Xerces Native Interface

Name: javax/mail/search/FromTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: x+5mIhEcfAXJ/sUmZhH1ZxHaG4g=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/BASE64DecoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: ZSQx/Xuh240EOCqvhQUa8UQQOh0=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/AString.class
SHA1-Digest: bluH0peRMsEKAiWMP1qzis3DMsc=

Name: org/apache/xml/serializer/utils/
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils
Implementation-Version: 2.7.0
Comment: Utilities used internally by the Serializer. Not for external
  use.

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Quota$Resource.class
SHA1-Digest: 3eBjXbAl4KtqOWEpvcH1D/RvcEQ=

Name: javax/mail/search/ReceivedDateTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: LWp9MpPLe4p6rErKZJ6TAWFQIwc=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BASE64MailboxDecoder.class
SHA1-Digest: lfv5JKcYNaWKMPVDOn4BH1r79DA=

Name: javax/mail/search/AddressTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: pb5Rfd3vghsJVORVFbLQUqFCdnk=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/FLAGS.class
SHA1-Digest: mb8PjIrqAtlNre35gTEGyZXpjSs=

Name: org/apache/log4j/
Implementation-Vendor: "Apache Software Foundation"
Implementation-Title: log4j
Implementation-Version: 1.2.14

Name: com/sun/mail/util/BASE64EncoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: PhRNdEecTpSsRiJY0pUZmmXcU6Q=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/message_rfc822.class
SHA1-Digest: 7f7lLHDJiiIYozmNRJdWXmanucc=

Name: javax/mail/search/AddressStringTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: Py9AXA8H4FCAA1Rpo3I+2fwSISM=

Name: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime
Implementation-Version: 2.1.4-b02-fcs

Name: javax/mail/Part.class
SHA1-Digest: 9G9aj3EQEFJkLkGaVyAjesSW1Jk=

Name: javax/mail/EventQueue$QueueElement.class
SHA1-Digest: kb93WyA+TadV3l1mZgGC43UqvKg=

Name: com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.class
SHA1-Digest: j3wY+vqZdAJDt5bYwAH8b9cXFVE=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/CRLFOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: rwRM031H5Ig0KwZzxonnczWv+Gc=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/TraceOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: WCddxU42jQ0RGVNqA5yGJFMq0a4=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Utility$Condition.class
SHA1-Digest: /RP1IP2+QlNdpHguqi8189/a+To=

Name: javax/mail/internet/UniqueValue.class
SHA1-Digest: vCW0ebHrlwjGPsbOMsBGX0WTMbg=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Folder.class
SHA1-Digest: WrNgKCK4DRFoeC6ho3nsu6I1QkI=

Name: javax/xml/xpath/
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.xml.xpath
Implementation-Version: 1.3.02
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: Java API for XML Processing
Implementation-URL: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp.html
Specification-Version: 1.3
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: com/sun/mail/util/BEncoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: 158qvZlZGzLcn6a63B9AUAXNLwQ=

Name: javax/xml/validation/
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.xml.validation
Implementation-Version: 1.3.02
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: Java API for XML Processing
Implementation-URL: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp.html
Specification-Version: 1.3
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: javax/mail/PasswordAuthentication.class
SHA1-Digest: AxiQvAJATUJleqC60z610xs8g+U=

Name: javax/mail/event/MailEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: u9B1y8KPBhV1Ed+aWQyRygUbMIo=

Name: javax/mail/search/NotTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: 9jEpMz7+rJDYS/tetftLnAfmX+g=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/SharedByteArrayOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: /vMClZ7vApKknSHh4DYTgxq8LfA=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed.class
SHA1-Digest: K+HJksRgguqxMKJBs5g4R6YJYzg=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/MessageLiteral.class
SHA1-Digest: j2NWZ8O36Q9/FOnXPBfbq1nxDdA=

Name: javax/mail/search/ComparisonTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: Hqg2WBMxwFjUeTR5siK6oPwzhJg=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$ProtocolCommand.class
SHA1-Digest: Cc5PabNTstl9FZGDbvKfazJYpIE=

Name: javax/mail/internet/HeaderTokenizer$Token.class
SHA1-Digest: SdpqfjRihm+RWmMXQjk4rLJDBOU=

Name: javax/mail/UIDFolder$FetchProfileItem.class
SHA1-Digest: UZ6YlRdOxpDooMPI151mGK6iwFk=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/UUEncoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: 1FKVJAR2xe3T8zlYClQKj+5QT+I=

Name: javax/mail/BodyPart.class
SHA1-Digest: BsFiU1h2qvnQYWF+pimUhYdFAc4=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Rights$Right.class
SHA1-Digest: MEdUSVTUiMgh/oVFPKQIsJCXIsM=

Name: javax/mail/Session$1.class
SHA1-Digest: e4wJlpIisoJspf9x4oSZOGI3kgw=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/ENVELOPE.class
SHA1-Digest: AKOoOtwyQs+R1gioc4dB4gYGlXg=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12.class
SHA1-Digest: eT4XVb3oRIvJ66uqfekxCwmckwE=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/text_xml.class
SHA1-Digest: g7n0q3rrqP8AB7DpixFPfZUTsGs=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$16.class
SHA1-Digest: 2SN4v7moBEXLRjwCjPEaQiWwFr8=

Name: javax/mail/internet/matchEnum.class
SHA1-Digest: AYU3f3sVLGSxNtVvpHgilUZtMdE=

Name: com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.class
SHA1-Digest: IpGFoVESnGL0JZ5nAehbn7dkF9A=

Name: javax/mail/internet/SharedInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: c2F/FBldF/b33VUKlcLjUNAuLjY=

Name: javax/mail/event/MessageCountAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: F4FDThh6Tw1mwpcB0x4leDu9sVI=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/text_plain.class
SHA1-Digest: pxlsPjnIr/1GOG19sL+DhVewDdE=

Name: javax/mail/IllegalWriteException.class
SHA1-Digest: uD4M1sQ1nnWMV+bRzoDpxKBQasM=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$7.class
SHA1-Digest: 9hF9nPPs1WwGrid1x+S0KxYhJTs=

Name: com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: B3x0//NSC0q9yO1h+1//o30T5NQ=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: lQwWSrVpg++AHFC+A5nOiVGaqk0=

Name: javax/mail/event/TransportEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: pnUMWFijO6HrDrKOri7+qjJvDMI=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/QPDecoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: t0U0mXoOcBmhtoFDiIUOeWkhLgY=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.class
SHA1-Digest: 5TM+LONcq9eJRXSr8kZiQ8RURhw=

Name: xmlsec
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: Apache-XML-Security-J
Implementation-Version: 1.3.0 ${TODAY}

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore$ConnectionPool.class
SHA1-Digest: /D/WTm4svWHBoEF6XSkgrzoGrWs=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$4.class
SHA1-Digest: iNTeoQpCZZ0whXKFRMMuT5ZGRd0=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.class
SHA1-Digest: gPfyYKWWL/oCdUd2Vb0m3uYqWpA=

Name: javax/mail/Message$RecipientType.class
SHA1-Digest: ZxVgRaRunSIe3CZDlzJMtzc3SJo=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPBodyPart.class
SHA1-Digest: RD1b0rrHv8PkoTG0+lf38u67J9s=

Name: javax/mail/event/ConnectionAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: 8RjzjNXIgyIXH8t2T2bpydcBdXM=

AComment: Xerces-J 2.7.1

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$9.class
SHA1-Digest: MQf35USIXPJrXjj5Ki1RSrvVodY=

Name: javax/mail/event/FolderAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: tI5Fs0LNbR4IjjKeY8V7TVyzAp8=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/CommandFailedException.class
SHA1-Digest: FisOBME0Jn/0jDFXtyP3YFtgNn0=

Name: javax/mail/UIDFolder.class
SHA1-Digest: qDcdba2rD5hvk4Quzsc3l/5nCYc=

Name: javax/mail/NoSuchProviderException.class
SHA1-Digest: iDaY5ddbHNXqCcj3Ax/lgjbYznY=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ResponseInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: NINscpCgiFusy38qZ3HPNGEDW4A=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/image_jpeg.class
SHA1-Digest: 6TaMpH7WcS1cmCIy8xim7c2mlMo=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Namespaces.class
SHA1-Digest: BNur7ins+4sfwuAAN73GtwQoex4=

Name: javax/mail/search/RecipientStringTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: 1DpAxvvp5gdr78CYLqGwto+8CQ8=

Name: javax/mail/StreamLoader.class
SHA1-Digest: g6CPWHycDJJb8j348nZJgiptnhI=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPProtocol.class
SHA1-Digest: Aq7kw1Ub31S7KU5YlN7DXqW5OAc=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$FetchProfileItem.class
SHA1-Digest: LkmXNiLVyrrVqMcCUnn9edV3fn0=

Name: javax/mail/MessagingException.class
SHA1-Digest: cL2aRjUjhxIC5JL+CcY0p9Ad+Js=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$1.class
SHA1-Digest: l8llUp8Gt6sj3cyskVkrNGzGCZ8=

Name: javax/mail/internet/AsciiOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: cu/3EooiZShegX1fHymNyl4Cth8=

Name: javax/mail/Folder$1.class
SHA1-Digest: OHS5c6BnZdXIgNrrBBx0mi6t7wE=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12$3.class
SHA1-Digest: yDdyXTFIs4BTndtx7OFKrFjAuQU=

Name: javax/mail/event/TransportAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: cvgC7kfs1+pCQaYoHMWV5/XCDKY=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ParsingException.class
SHA1-Digest: PRxKcl5jpj1vPZ0mAJsBAa2UutM=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ProtocolException.class
SHA1-Digest: 4on9Lc30QQL04SEyVMwC3oN5EAY=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/RFC822DATA.class
SHA1-Digest: sKQ0fzKLJc3jSlJhnZ/ttup0trg=

Name: javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: gxqAwr9Ky5QBQ4WLHaidz8Wfl0c=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Namespaces$Namespace.class
SHA1-Digest: MLQ6Lg884SnA22FsSGuyTU8pRQI=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/Argument.class
SHA1-Digest: fWv6G11Gdr7PTv1lXwv4Ouf1nJw=

Name: javax/mail/Service.class
SHA1-Digest: xrYis0Dww/bXojy8+7bNNCLhIMk=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$5.class
SHA1-Digest: 5/iaFe4/s7DD01HGuK8QpuZT3ns=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/MessageSet.class
SHA1-Digest: 0mPbryDKktQyU9DxoogzZI/OuRU=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$2.class
SHA1-Digest: ePbkzBKBH7BkdNRCH7JdHMKmkz8=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$3.class
SHA1-Digest: aiYwHPzTZExKxPxBHRAha393GEk=

Name: javax/mail/Provider.class
SHA1-Digest: dbZGmDHtZuDmyidl20bXUly3ntY=

Name: javax/mail/Store.class
SHA1-Digest: 6X6bFhPHLQAp042kca7jrYqB4A4=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/RFC822SIZE.class
SHA1-Digest: 7ZaQnODL+5VxGAb9ycDby9Ouevo=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/INTERNALDATE.class
SHA1-Digest: ZOQno39toT/YTc6HNUz9Ot5kslw=

Name: javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders.class
SHA1-Digest: RQeLWpUfmOqQfGWEu9FS5ooSci4=

Name: javax/mail/Flags$Flag.class
SHA1-Digest: 5tFlGWtctB1STMq6HFWqe3YPWdA=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage$RecipientType.class
SHA1-Digest: QUAovn/JOd/+1m4qD5xqVQmMSpI=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/Status.class
SHA1-Digest: SR9k4yO5yUi3auYkMROvXaSQj/c=

Name: javax/mail/Session$2.class
SHA1-Digest: zdKuQllpPYSwE5dM4TxikcU47D0=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12$1.class
SHA1-Digest: 78ePYKf7KntiHRdJeZxFhRlPqRM=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport.class
SHA1-Digest: qnl/waFwFYQyq91x1V1aJKwCBmE=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/ASCIIUtility.class
SHA1-Digest: Ita7PGvkIyz2jTTu9mx141dsXxc=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder$1.class
SHA1-Digest: qxsVgVMkqllunfxi5r1jLNJ0SAQ=

Name: javax/mail/Multipart.class
SHA1-Digest: HHrJ9a6oO/+IOtqFiyioBdwGono=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12$4.class
SHA1-Digest: NoAN8f0FUah3e/PGT3CeOUiofws=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$10.class
SHA1-Digest: alJp1A7OZ/Xt7nMBMGEWCMpZ3mw=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/Quota.class
SHA1-Digest: j7ukKu2EeyGl/eAHZ+/ECrdNCz0=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BODY.class
SHA1-Digest: v0SA4XHDRpb0BCGg8kSocc0T30Y=

Name: javax/mail/Folder.class
SHA1-Digest: XoN7VPgeYxy4m+kCXGZ/nirX4oA=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BASE64MailboxEncoder.class
SHA1-Digest: iydFl9/wfg/yHBRrdSREJB3QBzI=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/QEncoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: tvaNY/BbDF2f2RzwolLV9GJ28g8=

Name: javax/mail/search/BodyTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: VenGJGuQmPZg+hZXZu4TGpX60wk=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPAddress.class
SHA1-Digest: KpETkeeQHQAD71WnOab9yDJyK0o=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$12.class
SHA1-Digest: 7eCG0Qe4DSe2ItuD/QrxWKBZHyI=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/SharedByteArrayInputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: 7KmfanNYyL3FvWv1/BG6LnYuNUA=

Name: javax/mail/internet/AddressException.class
SHA1-Digest: nmhHxY3nr8aaWER9KJswQnH/QPA=

Name: javax/mail/internet/HeaderTokenizer.class
SHA1-Digest: evwKRf8YAcnb4E1fLoXQM04KKDs=

Name: javax/mail/search/StringTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: eFEtsGgraACS3eRdhJYG+AerOy4=

Name: javax/mail/Flags.class
SHA1-Digest: VQdqDOtD5OuUb5Tks3n23OGskqc=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Status.class
SHA1-Digest: zSxif54SoBUiOYxeDwmfE/pHsK4=

Name: javax/mail/search/FromStringTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: wQSeBiGfGcNWhmePYpfJWcFFSdg=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/Response.class
SHA1-Digest: +akWna4FnmxyvZXRTnlTJmAdcY8=

Name: javax/mail/event/StoreListener.class
SHA1-Digest: +BM2MswIMrP3NN235/bFi+oCxDg=

Name: javax/mail/search/SentDateTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: rmVF+9qq651v1D5sHDooDB0wn5Y=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.class
SHA1-Digest: Jq5L22gxOICsQIi3Ze5jGlom5NM=

Name: javax/mail/MethodNotSupportedException.class
SHA1-Digest: GZ0I8HAcU5XdSKh2v7UfmO7lSqQ=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MailDateFormat.class
SHA1-Digest: HBPhiNfmi6tT/fAtlkyH7DBIMYg=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/Atom.class
SHA1-Digest: RVCLbNsyfmwlX0+ftqL58RrM6wI=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/ByteArray.class
SHA1-Digest: fTXycdWBnCWVYNUQebkjG+GT9u8=

Name: com/sun/mail/iap/Protocol.class
SHA1-Digest: pmZrpW1MvmKsNOPy5+W+CSxA1vE=

Name: javax/mail/internet/MimePartDataSource.class
SHA1-Digest: g5wQCNeUiNfmDw5Xuj1z/9P3diM=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/UUDecoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: oH5S9MZumNu8SpE1RxHVOjONPMU=

Name: javax/mail/search/RecipientTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: p+BJdGRzjmgR9Pij0ONNlPHo7OA=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/UID.class
SHA1-Digest: eGTQIQT9Z9jmP9GTZkcqMpdD7HI=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$13.class
SHA1-Digest: 4i39Jgvxw/dEexNwwKMw6B5n3oA=

Name: javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: yjIhhlZywZvYMXYZaVO6lk4IPUo=

Name: javax/mail/event/MessageCountEvent.class
SHA1-Digest: o2C/asucfo+KOYru8x7VeJsn8kw=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/DefaultFolder.class
SHA1-Digest: GsDmlFLNmrbfYTrSTMTGWECJFck=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPNestedMessage.class
SHA1-Digest: mfO927rh3+qEycUHWmk4pwEF/LM=

Name: javax/mail/SecuritySupport12$5.class
SHA1-Digest: i7seT9W0U85Jd2nKKjMSx6zgp8E=

Name: com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Message.class
SHA1-Digest: S/w1qKjKQto7oUrZQgNz/1v+uJo=

Name: javax/mail/search/SizeTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: 4of7XuYNceiEA/lBA6xGAXcK4Xo=

Name: javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.class
SHA1-Digest: 71RGXBkLFr0AgQLh5PEspZilkB0=

Name: javax/mail/event/ConnectionListener.class
SHA1-Digest: 4a5cGqI0/mOkMii7FKm6AFct87k=

Name: javax/mail/internet/ParseException.class
SHA1-Digest: I/lti4miXWMbcfnqpz9B3JxTQKs=

Name: javax/mail/MessageContext.class
SHA1-Digest: lVLgWBtydsok5CyBBmfmCZEtqCk=

Name: javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.class
SHA1-Digest: gc4Tg1cF79H1C95Wp+IPDFlNHFQ=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$8.class
SHA1-Digest: JFPV/sFmaiU2Z6f5xiM4jKd6W98=

Name: javax/mail/internet/ContentType.class
SHA1-Digest: 6+UWkjb+XJlZzA1QHVPAcKVrYZk=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/LengthCounter.class
SHA1-Digest: eSbjrIQyrkq9zP8NSivzcH3WwRA=

Name: javax/xml/parsers/
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.xml.parsers
Implementation-Version: 1.3.02
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: Java API for XML Processing
Implementation-URL: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp.html
Specification-Version: 1.3
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: javax/mail/StoreClosedException.class
SHA1-Digest: yujVPRQ6gZ+KvY8ooBhUB//p5iU=

Name: javassist/

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$14.class
SHA1-Digest: cuazmZMG6nzn/imJnlXNQaTwpXY=

Name: javax/mail/Provider$Type.class
SHA1-Digest: RcBrLjSqBKbkGphUggeKQ8tmEyU=

Name: javax/mail/Service$1.class
SHA1-Digest: bBcqbuXIYK/pb3sTabo2Uld357Q=

Name: org/w3c/dom/ls/
Implementation-Vendor: World Wide Web Consortium
Implementation-Title: org.w3c.dom.ls
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Vendor: World Wide Web Consortium
Specification-Title: Document Object Model, Level 3 Load and Save
Implementation-URL: http://www.w3c.org/DOM/
Specification-Version: 1.0
Comment: based on xml-commons external 1.3.02

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$11.class
SHA1-Digest: +wtemvzDRw+zsO1mzBNhdyDXH7A=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/QDecoderStream.class
SHA1-Digest: M6+HVAW/8N4oOb88TOW+tHuk0mQ=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder.class
SHA1-Digest: VUosUn+a14PkAQGfJrbeL+4vj1g=

Name: javax/mail/event/FolderListener.class
SHA1-Digest: jqyODyE3T/VwXhIxZxtt2HKNfRE=

Name: com/sun/mail/util/LineOutputStream.class
SHA1-Digest: 9iehnKKwfZLXws9+dOwvIf2T58Q=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/text_html.class
SHA1-Digest: 6wEn4h3CORSNSHsC4RULxcumKD4=

Name: javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.class
SHA1-Digest: Y/DnFhVvjkIMkoV+0T8TXX0uERs=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/MailboxInfo.class
SHA1-Digest: X++C/B5b480R2j2rQDR4mqMf0o0=

Name: javax/mail/FetchProfile$Item.class
SHA1-Digest: YZ+BcYG1+A9vIxiM/W4iR7JT8/A=

Name: javax/mail/Authenticator.class
SHA1-Digest: mMAnLkTKyL7vIjp5a4Xh6FTkX4M=

Name: com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$17.class
SHA1-Digest: LwVyEhLhp83Kn7kqKqk8I6eFGqg=

Name: javax/mail/SendFailedException.class
SHA1-Digest: ejXXQU/1Npebx+Wu8U94NzNuM8w=

Name: com/sun/mail/handlers/image_gif.class
SHA1-Digest: sJ1kzJrdJJCjgrUs6CTtUqQJokQ=
```

Comment: How do you load the application context xml file in your code?

Comment: Could you show us (the important part of) the content of the exported JAR file? And also the Class-Path entry in the MANIFEST.MF file inside the META-INF directory of that JAR file?

Comment: Wait...  I am finding those information...  Sorry I am a newbie...

Comment: META-INF.MF has been showned.
Which part is the important part of the JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the location of the  "scanimagereport-data.xml" in the Class-Path: entry of your MANFIEST.INF